# QGIS version 2.18.1 "Python error: Couldn't load plugin 'processing'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I am running QGIS version 2.18.1 (overnight build) on a Windows 7 64-bit OS.

There appears to be an issue loading my processing plugins, which is obviously an issue when working with GIS. I have taken a look at other similar posts, however, there doesn't seem to be any solutions aside from un/reinstalling the program (which I have already tried). I must also note that I have almost zero experience with programming and code writing.

Upon launching QGIS an error is displayed stating "Python error: Couldn't load plugin 'processing' See message log (Python Error) for more detail". The message found in the message log under Python Error is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 308, in loadPlugin
                __import__(packageName)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
                from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 31, in <module>
                from processing.core.Processing import Processing
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 55, in <module>
                from processing.algs.qgis.QGISAlgorithmProvider import QGISAlgorithmProvider
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\QGISAlgorithmProvider.py", line 109, in <module>
                from .RasterLayerStatistics import RasterLayerStatistics
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\RasterLayerStatistics.py", line 36, in <module>
                from processing.tools import raster
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python/plugins\processing\tools\raster.py", line 29, in <module>
                import numpy
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
                import add_newdocs
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
                from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
                from type_check import *
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
                import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
                import multiarray
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-rel-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
                mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
            ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: Why don't you use the standard `qgis` package? Nightly builds are known to fail from time to time.